# how to add days / weeks from separate field in start date to get end date in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my form , I have 3 fields.

```
<input name="course_duration" id="course_duration" type="text"> (A numeric value which denotes 'Weeks'
<input name="course_start" id="course_start" type="text">
<input name="course_end" id="course_end" type="text">
```

I am using datepicker jquery and I want to fillup course_end date automatically by adding number of weeks from value inserted in course_duration field + course_start date

currently I am using following javascript code to popup calendar and selecting dates for course_start and course_end manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#course_start').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('#course_end').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/egq1ef5b/)

Comment: data format of `course_duration`? also please create a fiddle and share here so that its easy for us to help you.

Comment: @CerlinBoss it is a number e.g. 4 or 8 (weeks).

Comment: @CerlinBoss JSFIDDLE is added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the week from course_duration
var weeks = $('#course_duration').val();

// Get the selected date from startDate
var startDate = $('#course_start').datepicker('getDate');
var d = new Date(startDate);

// Add weeks to the selected date, multiply with 7 to get days
var newDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + weeks * 7);

// Set the new date to the course endDate
$('#course_end').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/egq1ef5b/2/)**